# Libgdx - Screen tearing (or artifacts) while in fullscreen

Tags: java, libgdx, sprites, image

I have a problem with libgdx, fullscreen and what I believe is screen tearing or any other sort of artifact.

In windowed mode, everything works fine, but when i switch to fullscreen, moving sprites create some sort of screen tearing effect:

[image: screen tearing on player character]

Had to take a photo with my phone, because using the print button does not work in fullscreen, and I could not capture the screen tearing effect using a libgdx "TakeScreenshot" Function.

I am using a TexturePacker and I tried changing the Filtering (Nearest, Linear) as well as edgePadding and duplicatePadding with no positive result.

I enabled vSync which also did not fix the problem.

Maybe anyone has encountered such a problem and can lend a helping hand.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*

This is how i enabled vSync:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.vSyncEnabled = true;
//some other config stuff
new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
```

Comment: Show us how you enable V-Sync

Comment: Might be a driver setting on your machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Following Ocelots hint, I checked whether my framerate was really running at my monitors refresh rate, which it did not (so vSync was disabled).

Somehow the LwjglApplicationConfiguration applies all the settings I hand over, except for vsync. Not really sure why.

I fixed the whole thing with a

```
Gdx.graphics.setVsync(true);
```

call in the core project.

This correctly applies vSync and removes any artifacts or jittering.